# How to integration Citrus framework and BBD Cucumber

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, testng, citrus-framework

I've a task intergrating the BBD with the Citrus Frimework.
The BBD we use the Cucumber and read the test case in the feature file like this

Feature: Person Management

person_management.feature

```
Scenario: Check the informations from an person
    Given the person management system is initialized with the following data
      | id  |
      | 1   | 
    Then the name of Person will be Patrick.
```

We have 
PersonTest (use Junit)

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class PersonTest {

}
```

public class PersonSteps {
    PersonManager manager;

```
@Given("^the person management system is initialized with the following data$")
public void the_person_management_system_is_initialized_with_the_following_data(final List<Person> persons) throws Throwable {
    manager = new PersonManager(persons);
}

@Then("^Then the name of Person will be (\\d+)$")
public void the_name_of_person_will_be(final String name) throws Throwable {
    assertThat(manager.getCurrentPersonName(), equalTo(name));
}
```

}

The problem that the PersonTest run as Junit test

And my Citrus use the testcase with TestNG and xml testcase
Like this

```
@Test
public class PersonCitrusTest extends AbstractTestNGCitrusTest {

    /**
     * Test find company by id
     */
    @CitrusXmlTest(name = "findPersonTestCase")
    public void findPersonTestCase() {
    }

    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spring:beans xmlns="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/testcase"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/testcase"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                  http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/testcase http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/testcase/citrus-testcase.xsd
                                  http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/testcase http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/http/testcase/citrus-http-testcase.xsd">
    <testcase name="findPersonTestCase">
        <description>Test Find Person</description>
        <variables>
            <variable name="personId" value="1"></variable>
        </variables>
        <actions>

            <!--
            1. Get Person
            2. Check the name of person
             -->
```

---

So how could I integrate both of them? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the Citrus Java DSL inside the Cucumber step definition. Something like this:

```
public class PersonSteps {
    private Citrus citrus;
    private TestRunner runner;

    private PersonManager manager;

    @Before
    public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {
        citrus = Citrus.newInstance();
        runner = new DefaultTestRunner(citrus.getApplicationContext(), citrus.createTestContext());
    }

    @Given("^the person management system is initialized with the following data$")
    public void the_person_management_system_is_initialized_with_the_following_data(final List<Person> persons) throws Throwable {
         manager = new PersonManager(persons);

         runner.variable("personId", "1");
         runner.echo("TODO: Get person");
    }

    @Then("^Then the name of Person will be (\\d+)$")
    public void the_name_of_person_will_be(final String name) throws Throwable {
        assertThat(manager.getCurrentPersonName(), equalTo(name));

        runner.echo("TODO: Verify person");
    }
}
```

You have to write some glue code in @Before annotated method in order to prepare Citrus for the Cucumber JUnit test. I don't think that you can do the same with XML test cases in Citrus so you have to use the Java DSL here.

Comment: I've tried many way before receiving your feedback and also use the dsl for this . like : Citrus citrus = Citrus.newInstance(); TestDesigner testDesigner = new DefaultTestDesigner(citrus.getApplicationContext(), citrus.createTestContext()); testDesigner.send(httpClient).payload("").http().method(HttpMethod.GET).path(ur‌​i); And then we receive the response like this ReceiveHttpMessageBuilder status = testDesigner.receive(httpClient).messageType(MessageType.JSON).http(); status.validateScript(jsonScript);..... we could use the groovy script and set value for a memory java object.